# Passing object model to another AsyncTask from other AsyncTask and adding data to model doesn't render

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview

This is my first async task, which gets called first, it gets data from server and then `onPostExecute` it executes other async task, which downloads and sets image.

```
private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String content;
    private String error = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(params[0]);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            content = client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            error = e.getMessage();
            cancel(true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (error == null) {
            try {
                JSONObject dataDishes = new JSONObject(content);
                Log.d("DISHES", dataDishes.toString());

                ArrayList<DishModel> dishData = new ArrayList<DishModel>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

                    DishModel model = new DishModel();

                    model.setName("Company " + i);
                    model.setDesc("desc" + i);
                    //TODO: set data img
                    new GetImage(model).execute("http://example.com/" + (i + 1) + ".png");
                    dishData.add(model);
                }

                ListView listAllDishes = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView);

                DishRowAdapter adapterAllDishes = new DishRowAdapter(getActivity(),
                        R.layout.dish_row, dishData);

                listAllDishes.setAdapter(adapterAllDishes);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("DISHES", e.toString());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("DISHES", error);
        }
    }
}
```

This is another async task, it downloads image and `onPostExecute` it sets image to passed model.

```
private class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private DishModel model;
    private Bitmap bmp;

    public getImage(DishModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            Log.d("DISHES", params[0]);
            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("DISHES", e.toString());
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d("DISHES", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        model.setPhoto(bmp);
    }
}
```

It works if I do both data/image download proccess in one `AsyncTask doInBackground(String... params)`, but it doesnt when I split data and image downloading into seperate async tasks. Furthermore I dont get any exceptions or errors.

UPDATE: Images shows up when i switch views..

Answer (score 0):

At first, getImage and getData are classes, and classes names in Java are capitalized.

Technically, you can run another AsyncTask from `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5780190/1159507
So, try to put the breakpoint in second AsyncTask call and debug is it called.

Comment: I do call GetImage in onPostExecute and it works. I think something is wrong with model passing and setting image in another async task.. but I am not sure.

Comment: If it works in one AsyncTask you can compare in debuger whats go wrong  if you use two.

Comment: Just noticed, that images appears if I switch to another tab and switch back - images appears..