# async task not running when called from other async task

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

```
class TestAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    v.findViewById(R.id.loadinglayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    v.findViewById(R.id.wholecontentlayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    callAPI();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    v.findViewById(R.id.loadinglayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    v.findViewById(R.id.wholecontentlayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}



public void callAPI ()
{
    RequestInterface requestInterface = new RequestImplementation();
    requestInterface.setUrl("https://api.myjson.com/bins/vl9pp");
    ConnectionExecutor connectionExecutor = new 
    ConnectionImplementation();
    ResponseInterface temp = null;
    try {
       temp = connectionExecutor.executeConnection(requestInterface);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   rangeText.setText(temp.getPayload());
}
```

Call API function will call a method of another class where HttpConnection is done.

If the function is directly called from `onViewCreated()` in fragment then it works. If I call it from another async task it returns nothing.

I am actually trying to show a progress bar when the callApi function is called.

Comment: Can you post the code from where are you calling it from another asynctask?

Comment: You calling TestAsync class right .. Can you show that code?

Comment: Yeah sure ! I am calling TestAsync. But when I call calAPI directly it works.

Comment: @fluffyBatman I am calling an implementation from this callAPI

Comment: @AbhishekVeenakkat What's the error you are getting?

Comment: What does it say in the LogCat? Please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not allowed to start an AsyncTask outside the UI thread. `doInBackground` is outside the UI thread.

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html:

> Threading rules
>
> ...
>
> The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread.

Comment: Then how can I show a progress bar while callAPI is called ?

Answer (score 0):

call it on onPostExecute method

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
v.findViewById(R.id.loadinglayout).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
v.findViewById(R.id.wholecontentlayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  callAPI();
}}
```

Comment: Let me try..But I guess I wont be able to show a progress bar while loading doing so.

Comment: Calling from onPostExecute works !! But I need it to be done in the background :(

Comment: I dont think it is possible to do that in doInBackground....You cannot do anything which changes interface in doInBackground

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5780190/2709580)

> only inside onProgressUpdate() or onPostExecute() since these methods
>   runs on the UI thread. Therefore, start the second AsyncTask on the UI
>   thread by choosing one of the two methods listed above.

Simply put, if you're in need of firing up AsyncTask within another AsyncTask, it must be called from either `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()` since they resides in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

To show the ProgressBar to illumilate the task is running, you should show your progress bar in `onPreExecute()` and hide it in `onPostExecute(Result)`.

```
 AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> yourTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        /**
         * Show your progress bar:
         */
        yourProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        /**
         * Do your stuffs in background thread
         */
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        /**
         * Hide your progress bar:
         */
        yourProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
};
```

Run the task: `yourTask.execute();`

`onPostExecute(Result)` method will get called when the task completed.